# Factory_girl returning objects and fabricator returning an empty array why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, fixtures, fabrication-gem

our test code is currently using `factory_girl` and I am trying to use `fabrication` for my tests to generate objects.

**`In Factory_Girl`**

```
batch = FactoryGirl.create(:transaction_batch)
puts batch  # print out a transaction object
```

**`In Factory Girls`**

```
batch = Fabricator(:transaction_batch)
puts batch # prints out an empty array
```

Could anyone tell me why the Fabricator is returning an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FactoryGirl` defines it's factories in `spec/factories/transaction.rb`, and there you have something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction_batch do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
  end
end
```

The `Fabricator` uses "fabrications" from a different location, like `spec/fabricators/transaction_fabricator.rb`

And there you don't have defined fabrication. That is the reason, or you have a blank fabrication like:

```
Fabricator(:transaction_batch) do
end
```

Create a fabrication for Fabricator, and you should be fine.